# How to find certain files and move them to a new directory in the same command?

Tags: bash, shell, find, directory

So I was looking around and all I have found is how to do this only if the directory is already made, which is this:

```
find source -name '*.z' -exec cp {} destination \;
```

But how can I make a new directory where I want to send these files in the same command? This is what I have tried but with no success:

```
find source -name '*.z' -exec cp {} | mkdir newDirectory \;
```

Comment: I don't understand why you aren't just using `mkdir newDirectory; find … -exec cp {} newDirectory \;`

Answer (score 11):

One option is to use the `install` command instead of `cp`. It has an option to create all of the leading directories.

```
find source -name '*.z' -exec install -D {} dest \;
```

Comment: On OSX `-d` must be used instead of capital `-D`.

Answer (score 1):

You [can't pipe data](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/93334/22222) to `mkdir` that way. You could do something like this:

```
find source -name '*.z' -exec sh -c 'mkdir -p newDirectory && cp "$@" newDirectory' _ {} +
```

or (assuming file names not containing newlines)

```
find source -name '*.z' | while IFS= read -r foo; do 
   mkdir -p newDirectory;
   cp "$foo" newDirectory;
done
```

or if you only want to create one directory, so the name is always the same:

```
mkdir newDirectory; find source -name '*.z' -exec cp {} newDirectory \;
```

Comment: Does find actually change the working directory as it goes?  Won't this try making a directory in the same place each time and copy all the files into it?  If he wanted them all in one directory, I can't see why he'd need to create the directory as he worked...

Comment: Is there any way to do the first way without a bash statement? Possibly piped?

Comment: @kurtm see updated answer, and yes, apparently `find` changes the CWD as it goes, it will create the directory in the same place.

Comment: @John see updated answer. You cannot pipe data to `mkdir`.

Comment: @terdon Okay.  I wasn't sure since it give relatives paths for output.

Comment: @kurtm it was a good point, neither was I. Had to test to check.

Comment: @terdon So find puts something different in place of {} than it does when it does `-print`?

Comment: @kurtm really don't know. I remember there was a question on the site about this. In ay case, I tested and when the `.z` file was in a subdirectory, `find` still copied to the `newDir` in the parent so it seems to deal somehow. My guess is that since it uses the full path, it won't cd into the directory a file was found in when executing `-exec` calls. If you want more details that that, try pinging one of the heavyweights in chat :).

Comment: @kurtm `find` does not change the working directory (except with `-execdir`, which does exactly that). A pipe would be a bash statement — why don't you want to do this the straightforward way?

Comment: @Gilles You asking me or OP?  I like straightforward, I was just asking terdon about his proposed solution.