# Why the following redirection doesn’t work?

Tags: linux, io-redirection, ls

i typed the following command

```
which cp | ls -l
```

It didn’t work as i expected. I wanted that the output of the which command will be a path name. So the ls command will show the information about the path or that file.
Although  `which cp | less` works what is supposed to. But why don’t  `which cp | ls -l` works as expected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't certain programs (like readlink) take input from a pipe?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93334/why-cant-certain-programs-like-readlink-take-input-from-a-pipe) ... or more closely: [whereis, pipline and ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364079/whereis-pipline-and-ls)

Comment: use xargs then `which cp | xargs ls -l`